# How to access $scope from $resource

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I need to splice an array on success.  How do I call back out to my $scope.list in order to remove an item from the list array?  Is that how I should do it or is there a better way?  Like bubbling an "update" or something?

```
var phonecatServices = angular.module('phonecatServices', ['ngResource']);
    var urlBase = 'http://example.com/api/';

    function resourceErrorHandler(response) {

        console.log("error");
    }
    function resourceResponseHandler(response) {
        console.log($scope.list);

        $scope.list.data.splice(index, 1);
        console.log("success");
    }
    phonecatServices.factory('api_resource', ['$resource',
      function($resource){
        return $resource(urlBase+':api_resource/:id.json', {}, {
          query: {method:'GET', isArray:false},
          save:{method:'POST', isArray:false},
          delete:{method:'DELETE', isArray:false, interceptor:{response:resourceResponseHandler, responseError:resourceErrorHandler}},
         });
      }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make $scope an argument in the functions and pass it with the method call in the controllers, or bundle it in the response object.